# Find the range of this function $f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$, using first derivative test.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x^2}$$
I am able to find the range using other methods ,but I am not able to get the correct range using first derivative test. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It seems the range should be $-1/2 \leq f(x) \leq 1/2,$ unless I've forgotten calculus completely. The min occurs at $x=-1,$ the max at $x=1.$  The sign of $f'$ will depend on the sign of the numerator, as the denominator is always positive.

Comment: By the way, what did you compute $f'$ to be?

Comment: Chris your answer is correct and made me realise a silly mistake

Comment: turns out i was getting min and max at -1 and 1 only, but WAS THINKING THESE TO BE THE y VALUES ‍♂️

Comment: @ChrisLeary thanks

Comment: Glad to help, even in a small way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you do not need derivatives for computing the range. Since $1+x^2 > 0$ for any $x$, the equation
$$ \frac{x}{1+x^2} = k \qquad \text{for some }k\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$$
has at least a solution iff $kx^2-x+k$ has at least a real root. Such quadratic polynomial has at least a real root iff its discriminant is $\geq 0$, i.e. iff $1-4k^2\geq 0$. It follows that the range of your function is $\left[-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right]$.

That also follows from the AM-GM inequality and the fact that $f(x)$ is an odd function. For any $x\geq 0$ we have $1+x^2\geq 2x$, hence $f(x)\leq\frac{1}{2}$, with equality attained only at $x=1$.

Comment: +1 Note the $k=0$ case is separate since that doesn't lead to a quadratic in $x$.

Comment: Thanks , but I was able to solve the problem using these methods, I was just making a silly mistake when I was using derivatives, which was really bugging me!